# Please help me on creating ssl certificate for Azure service Principal in Python

Tags: ssl, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0, azure-service-principal, microsoft-graph-api

I have created service principal but there is no proper code or I don't know exactly how to create SSL certificate for Azure Service Principal in Python..
Please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft Graph REST API endpoint [servicePrincipal: addKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-addkey?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript) to create a certificate for the service principal provided you have the service principal id in Graph Context.

In your python script you can perform a HTTP request like below.

```
import requests

payload = {
    "keyCredential": {
        "type": "AsymmetricX509Cert",
        "usage": "Verify",
        "key": "MIIDYDCCAki..."
    },
    "passwordCredential": null,
    "proof":"eyJ0eXAiOiJ..."
}

r = requests.post(r'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{id}/addKey', data=payload)
```

I have not tested the request in python but should work as it is just REST api.

Comment: How to generate key in Key credential? @Danstan